# How to draw a chart using C# and .net 4 built-in chart control?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, charts

How to draw a chart which looks exactly the same as one on the picture using C# and .net 4 built-in chart control ?
Important are X and Y axis and there markings, and I don't want any graph line, just empty chart.

[image]

I'd be relly grateful for code snipet. Best regards, Primoz.

---

EDIT:
Problems that I have

- don't know how to put sign for
  degrees Celsius in the corner
- dont' know how to put date and time
  in four hour interval on the X axis

I'm using win forms and bult-in chart control.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The units for date/time axes are days. Since there are 6 4-hour intervals in a day, to get 4-hour intervals on the X-axis, use `AxisX.Interval = 1.0/6;`

Alternately, you can set the interval type to hours and then set it to 4:

```
AxisX.IntervalType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.DateTimeIntervalType.Hours;
AxisX.Interval = 4;
```

I don't see any obvious way to put the axis name in the corner. You can come close with a hack like this:

```
var title = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Title("\x00b0C");
title.Position.Y = 90;
title.Position.X = 5;
chart.Titles.Add(title);
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which technology you prefer. WPF for example has a great support for charting, take a look here: http://wpf.codeplex.com/

Example code: http://www.studentguru.gr/blogs/solidus/archive/2009/10/08/wpf-toolkit-part-1.aspx, http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/BarChartWPF11192009112620AM/BarChartWPF.aspx